# How can I use the Java stream in order to create an array iterating in all the element of a nested collection?

Tags: java, java-stream, java-17

I am working on a Java application and I am trying to understand if **Stream** concept can be useful for my use case.

I am trying to do something similar to what I found into an example but my use case seems to be more complex. This was the original example:

```
String[] profili = utente.getRuoli()
                 .stream().map(a -> "ROLE_" + a).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Basically it is creating an array starting from a stream.

Following my situation. I have this main **User** DTO class representing an user:

```
@Data
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String surname;
    private char sex;
    private Date birthdate;
    private String taxCode;
    private String eMail;
    private String pswd;
    private String contactNumber;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Set<Address> addressesList;
    private Set<UserType> userTypes;   
}
```

The previous DTO class contains this field representing a collection of user types (for example "ADMIN", "READER", "WRITER", etcetc). This because an user can have multiple types:

```
private Set<UserType> userTypes;
```

This is the **UserType** structure:

```
@Data
public class UserType {
    private int id;
    private String typeName;
    private String description;
    Set<Operation> operations;
}
```

Also this class contains a field representing  a collection of operations (this because a user type can have multiple operation that can perform on the system), this field:

```
Set<Operation> operations;
```

Now I am asking if I can use the stream in a similar way to the original example in order to create an array  of all the operations contained into all the user types.

Is it possible? What could be a smart solution? Or maybe the best way is the "old style" (iterate on all the object into the **userTypes** Set, then iterate on all the element into the **operations** Set and manually add to an array?). It will work but what could be a neat and elegant solution using stream? (if exist)

Comment: Do you want a single collection of all distinct operations for all users? Or the collection of operations for a given user? What is the type of the result you seek?

Comment: Exactly: a single collection of all the operations

Comment: All operations for a single user, or all operations for all users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `flatMap()` on the operations `Set`, with `distinct()`:

```
Operation[] operations = user.getUserTypes().stream()
  .map(UserType::getOperations)
  .flatMap(Set::stream)
  .distinct()
  .toArray(Operation[]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is just

```
userList.stream()
  .flatMap(user -> user.getUserTypes().stream())
  .flatMap(userType -> userType.getOperations().stream())
  .toArray(Operation[]::new);
```

...assuming you're using getters.  This gives you every operation for every user type for every user.

Comment: "assuming you're using getters", it's @Data from Lombok presumably. So yes, there are getters